# Expectation of a function given variance

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

A random variable $X$ has expectation $\mathbb E[X] = 5.6$ and variance $\mathbb{Var}[X] = 3.7$. The expectation $\mathbb E[X^2-5X+6]$ is equal to:

Attempt:

$$\mathbb{Var}[X] = 3.7$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X] = 5.6$$

$$\mathbb{Var}[X] = \mathbb E[X^2] - (\mathbb E[X])^2$$

$$3.7 = \mathbb E[X^2] - 5.6^2$$

$$\mathbb E[X^2] = 35.06$$

So,
$$\begin{align*} \mathbb E[X^2-5X+6] &= \mathbb E[X^2] -5 \mathbb E[X] + 6 \\
&=35.06 - 5*5.6 + 6 \\
&=13.06 \end{align*}$$
Right?

Comment: All right. So far so good. Now add them all up.

Comment: Hi ive done some more again. Is it right?

Comment: It's correct. Perfect. But this question has nothing to do with a poisson distribution, it applies to any distribution